# Sign in pop not coming when using basic-auth with axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, basic-authentication

Just added basic authentication in my node app using **basic-auth** for specific route. When i try to open it directly through browser browser's signin popup is coming asking for username and password. but when i hit the same API using **react axios** it is giving me 401 no signin popup coming.

**Here is the code from my node app:**

```
  const auth = require("basic-auth");
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
  let user = auth(req);
  if (authRquiredApis.includes(req.url)) {
    if (user === undefined || !isAuthorizedUser(user)) {
      res.statusCode = 401;
      res.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", 'Basic realm="Node"');
      res.end("Unauthorized");
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

**Here is the code for react axios**:

```
 import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  timeout: 120000,
});
```

**and in another file i am making call like:**

```
import { getDataUrl } from "./apiName";
import axios from "./axios";
export const getData = async (data) => {
  return await axios.get(getDataUrl);
};
```

For testing purpose i have deployed a test api:

https://data.thecyberintel.com/tciserver/testdata
Hitting this on browser will **ask for authentication**
enter **"admin" "admin"** to get response.

https://www.thecyberintel.com/#/test
This url internally hitting same api but **getting 401**

Comment: Hey. Did you find a solution? I have the same question.